# Favicon.ico not working after multiple attemps

Tags: html, favicon

I have been trying to add a favicon to my code and it is not working. I have generated a code on google chrome favicon generator as well as placed the zip file in my root directory. Please help?

Comment: Hi. Just to be sure: Did you place the zip archive in the root directory, or unzip it into it?

Comment: Nowadays it would be more advisable to use SVG icons instead of .ico files, if you do not need to support quite old platforms. Here is a great article on how to provide an icon in up-to-date formats for different platforms: [How to Favicon in 2022](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/how-to-favicon-in-2021-six-files-that-fit-most-needs)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.